# Combine Bottom Navigation with NavHostController Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, bottom-navigation-bar

I am trying to implement navigation in my Android app using JetpackCompose.
What I am trying to do is I have a Bottom Bar with 4 buttons (Home, categories, cart, settings)
Each of this screens have its own navigationHostController and multiple screens inside that can be navidated forward and back.
My problem is the following, when I use bottom nav button to navigate to othe screen, I want my NavHost to remember that screen I have left at and show it to me.

Example:
In my **Home** tab i have **Screen A**, **Screen B**, and **Screen C**. I can Navigate A->B->C using button and also navigate back using the Back button.
In my **Category** Screen I have **Screen E** and **Screen D**.
If I am on my Home Tab **Screen C** and tap on my **Category Tab**, it will navigate me to the Category Tab, and if I click on **Home Tab** again, I will see Home Tab **Screen A** not the **Screen C** I was on when I left.

Is this funcionality Possible in Android? I come from iOS world and this is done automatically there.
I am not putting any code in the question for now. Just want to know if this can be done in Jetpack and what would the steps be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation coming from SwiftUI development and wondering why this is so complicated in Jetpack. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, check the answer below

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I still don't get it. Would you mind posting the full setup with the nested `navigationHostController`s?

Comment: Its so many different files, If you share your code par where you create your bottomBar in scaffold, Ill fix your code for you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        B2CBottomBar(navController) {
            navController.navigate(it.route) {

                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    saveState = true
                }

                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true     //this is the part that preserves the state
            }
        }
    }
)
```

more detailed explanation can be found in [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).